# Pesquisa entre datas com between

Tags: sql

Tenho a seguinte pesquisa:

```
SELECT * FROM (`agendamentos`) 
WHERE `age_data_agendado_para` BETWEEN "2016-08-28" and "2016-08-30"
```

No banco de dados, eu tenho:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas no meu retorno, consigo buscar apenas dois registros, conforme o print_r():

```
Array - Campos de Pesquisa
(
    [age_senha] => 
    [age_nome] => 
    [age_cod_consultora_atendido] => 
    [age_cod_consultora_agendado] => 
    [age_data_inicial] => 2016-08-28
    [age_data_final] => 2016-08-30
    [age_status] => 
)
Array - Resultados Print_r
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [age_cod] => 6
            [age_cod_interessado] => 2
            [age_data_agendamento] => 2016-08-18 09:00:12
            [age_cod_consultora_agendado] => 1
            [age_cod_consultora_atendido] => 1
            [age_data_agendado_para] => 2016-08-29 08:00:00
            [age_senha] => MA2745
            [age_status] => 50
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [age_cod] => 7
            [age_cod_interessado] => 2
            [age_data_agendamento] => 2016-08-18 09:00:30
            [age_cod_consultora_agendado] => 1
            [age_cod_consultora_atendido] => 1
            [age_data_agendado_para] => 2016-08-29 08:00:00
            [age_senha] => MA2740
            [age_status] => 50
        )

)
```

Alguém consegue me dizer porque não consigo listar os itens todos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quando você usa somente a data no `BETWEEN`, o MySQL interpreta ela como se a hora fosse `00:00:00`.
Portanto a data `2016-08-18 09:00:30` não está entre as datas do seu filtro, ela é maior que `2016-08-18 00:00:00`.

Basta incluir o horário no filtro que já deve funcionar:

```
SELECT * FROM (`agendamentos`) 
WHERE `age_data_agendado_para` BETWEEN "2016-08-28 00:00:00" and "2016-08-30 23:59:59.999999"
```

Comment: Põe `"2016-08-30 23:59:59.999999"`

Comment: Bem isto, coloquei os horários e deu certo. Mas também tentei usar o CAST, e funcionou também.

Comment: Tá, é isso. Mas essas datas na sua conclusão não fazem sentido algum, vc utilizou o `age_data_agendamento` enquanto a consulta utiliza o `age_data_agendado_para`.

Comment: Acho `CAST` é uma ideia melhor. Porque colocando string para comparar com data você deixa o MySQL converter da maneira que ele quiser.

Comment: age_data_agendamento = Data em que foi lançado o agendamento no sistema, e age_data_agendado_para é para quando foi agendado.

Comment: Exemplo: A consultora Marina, lançou na data 15/01/2015 um agendamento para André para 20/01/2015. Endenteste?

Answer (score 4):

Outra opção seria usar um `CAST` para `DATE`

```
SELECT * FROM (`agendamentos`) WHERE CAST(age_data_agendado_para as DATE)
BETWEEN "2016-08-28" and "2016-08-30"
```

Answer (score 3):

O registro não é retornado pois o campo `age_data_agendado_para` é do tipo `datetime` e as datas passadas no seu `BETWEEN` são do tipo `date`.

Sendo assim, o seu `SELECT` pode ser lido da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT * FROM (`agendamentos`) WHERE `age_data_agendado_para` BETWEEN "2016-08-28 00:00:00.000000" and "2016-08-30 00:00:00.000000";
```

Logo, a data `2016-08-30 08:00:00` está fora do intervalo.

A correção mais adequada seria:

```
SELECT * FROM (`agendamentos`) WHERE `age_data_agendado_para` BETWEEN "2016-08-28 00:00:00.000000" and "2016-08-30 23:59:59.999999";
```

ou, se possível, um cast poderia resolver de forma mais elegante:

```
SELECT * FROM (`agendamentos`) WHERE CAST(age_data_agendado_para as DATE) BETWEEN "2016-08-28" and "2016-08-30";
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Mesmo resultado de antes! :(

Comment: Põe `"2016-08-30 23:59:59.999999"`.

Comment: Ajudou sim Lacobus, obrigado :)